# Getting scala program to run in eclipse

Tags: scala, program-entry-point

I have the following code in a file in eclipse Philsophers.scala in an eclipse project.
http://www.jakubkorab.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Philosophers.scala

When I right click to run, eclipse does not recognize the runner in this class. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that it's currently in the default package: it will run once you put it in a correct package, because the file itself specifies a package. The easiest thing is to remove:

```
package net.jakubkorab.philosophers
```